# Simplifying a proof that $f$ and $g$ are mutually inverse functions knowing that $f$ is an injection

Tags: functions, inverse-function

To prove that $f$ and $g$ are mutually inverse bijections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, it is necessary to prove:

- that really $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$;
- for every $x_0\in A$ and $y=f(x_0)$ we have $x_1=x_0$ for $x_1=g(y)$;
- for every $y_0\in B$ and $x=g(y_0)$ we have $y_1=y_0$ for $y_1=f(x)$.

Now suppose we already know that $f$ is an injection. Knowing this which items of the above list may be skipped without breaking the proof that they are mutually inverse?

Comment: Hm, it seems that all items involve $g$. So just removing an item would break the proof, even if I add that $f$ is an injection. Well, maybe there is any way to simplify the proof under assumption of injectivity of $f$ anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit easier if we rephrase your conditions thus:

- $f \in A \to B$ and $g \in B \to A$
- for all $a \in A$, $g(f(a)) = a$
- for all $b \in B$, $f(g(b)) = b$

If the third condition holds, and we put $f(a)$ for $b$, then we get:
$$
f(g(f(a)) = f(a)
$$
If also $f$ is an injection (so that $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y$), then we can "cancel" the $f$ on the two sides of the above equation giving:
$$
g(f(a)) = a
$$
which is the second condition.

So if $f$ is an injection you don't need to check the second condition. (By a somewhat similar argument, if $g$ is a surjection, you don't need to check the third condition.)